# How does one install a custom CA certificate on CentOS?

Tags: centos, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to install a certificate for my internal certificate server on a series of CentOS systems, and I'm finding the documentation on this to be almost non existent.

My end goal is to be able to use `git`, `curl`, and others against internal secure servers without errors.

On Ubuntu it's simple enough, you throw the certificate in a folder and run a command to generate a series of links to add the CA cert to the certification path.

I can not for the life of me find out how to do this on CentOS.. plenty of information is available on trusting random certificates. (To wit: create a symlink in `/etc/pki/tls/certs` to the PEM encoded cert file, named with the hash of the certificate. Didn't work for my CA, since the aforementioned apps still can't verify a certificate signed by the CA).

How do you install a new root CA on a CentOS system?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

As of CentOS 6+, there is a tool for this. Per [this guide](https://techjourney.net/update-add-ca-certificates-bundle-in-redhat-centos/), certificates can be installed first by enabling the system shared CA store:

```
update-ca-trust enable
```

Then placing the certificates to trust as CA's in `/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/` for high priority (non-overridable), or `/usr/share/pki/ca-trust-source/` (lower priority, overridable), and finally updating the system store with:

```
update-ca-trust extract
```

Et voila, system tools will now trust those certificates when making secure connections!

Comment: I commend you for coming back three years later with a solution. Thank you very much.

Comment: Just to point out for someone who isn't able to work this out, check if the certs have the required permissions.

Comment: I had to put my certificate into `/usr/share/pki/ca-trust-source/anchors` to make it working.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't think there is a single centralized way to do this in CentOS. I've spent a great deal of time trying to accomplish the same thing. The primary pki tls certificate store is used for a lot but definitely not everything.

My solution has been to maintain a puppet module that will push an updated certificate store to each location used per product. The basic logic is if a given store exists then add my custom entry.

This isn't perfect - some tomcat instances I deploy have an internal Java install with a non standard cacerts directory for one -that but it handles most of my needs.