# Managing a block of text with Puppet

Tags: centos, ssl-certificate, puppet, certificate-authority

I'm attempting to insert a block of text into my CA certificate file on CentOS hosts with Puppet. [I asked about this before, and it seems CentOS is sorely lacking in certificate management functions..](https://serverfault.com/questions/511812/how-does-one-install-a-custom-ca-certificate-on-centos).

What I need to do is get a rather large chunk of text representing my CA's certificate (passed through `openssl`'s info command for whatever silly reason) into my `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt` file and ensure it's always there, even if the host updates its CA file later from repo.

I *do not* want to manage the ca-bundle file in its entirety with Puppet. This is already being handled by the yum repositories the servers are pointed to.

Difficulty: Puppet doesn't officially have a way to manage chunks of text, only lines, using the `file_line` resource. Me attempting to be clever, though, thought you could use a newline-escaped "line" of text and manage that.

Well, sort of. It works, in that the text ends up in the file, but the problem is that it keeps getting re-added after each puppet run, like the code can't tell that it already exists.

For detail, the chunk of text looks a lot like this (truncated for obvious reasons :3)

```
$cacert = "Certificate:\n    Data:\n        Version: 3 (0x2)\n        Serial Number:\n            10:d8:83:91:-redacted-"
```

The line in my Puppet module looks like this:

```
class em_cacerts::centos inherits em_cacerts{
    file_line { 'ca-certificate':
            path => '/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt',
            line => $cacert,
            #match => "(see below)",
            ensure => present,
    }
```

I've tried all kinds of shenanigans with the `match` line (including using an `inline_template` to set the match regex to the entire contents of the `$cacert` variable, which works flawlessly in IRB, but not in Puppet) in an attempt to get it to recognize the text block already exists but it keeps getting re-added every time and just stacks up on top of itself..

I'm probably barking up the wrong tree here.. but anyways, that's part of the question.

- Is there a better way to accomplish this goal?
- If not, how do I get Puppet to realize the block of text already exists?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up solving this with an `exec` line:

```
class em_cacerts::centos inherits em_cacerts{
        exec { 'cent-ca-certificate':
                command => "/bin/echo '$centcacert' >> '$cabundlepath'",
                onlyif => "test ! `grep (redacted CA name) $cabundlepath`", 
                provider => 'shell',
        }
}
```

Yeah, it's using exec, which is officially discouraged, but this works reliably and uses absolute basic stuff that any CentOS box will have.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Typically I see files managed in their entirety using erb templates.  If you won't do that, you could have a script perform a sed command.  https://puppetlabs.com/blog/why-puppet-isnt-a-file-management-tool/

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the puppet concat module, which builds files from fragments. Or just manage a separate file and have a exec resource sed insert it into the file if not found with grep

Answer (score 0):

See also augeas.

http://augeas.net/

It aims to do exactly what you asked for.